# Inserting multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, insert, backup

How do I restore my data from a backup table `table1_bu` into a new table `new_table1`, which has the same structure? I need to insert all the rows from `table1_bu` into `new_table1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_table1(Id, Field1)
      SELECT Id, Field1
        FROM table1_bu
```

Comment: This will not work if the Id column is set to be an identity column

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to use the same IDs in the new table:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT new_table1 ON;

INSERT INTO new_table1
SELECT * FROM table1_bu;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT new_table1 OFF;
```

PS: SELECT INTO (as suggested by some) also works, but it's slightly less flexible in my experience. Therefore I've gotten used to this way of doing things :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
select * into new_table1 from table1_bu
```

Note that for this to work, new_table should not exist before running the statement, this will create AND populate the table.